# Drawing figure with perfect spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, mathcha

I'm trying to make a figure with a parabolic type curve that is equally spaced and looks uniform between the two axes. I made the following using [Mathcha.](https://www.mathcha.io)

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering




\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp33697970652864007] 
\draw  (131.5,215.73) -- (449.5,215.73)(192.5,80) -- (192.5,239) (442.5,210.73) -- (449.5,215.73) -- (442.5,220.73) (187.5,87) -- (192.5,80) -- (197.5,87)  ;
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp4413547073522268] 
\draw  (131.5,215.73) -- (449.5,215.73)(382.5,80) -- (382.5,239) (442.5,210.73) -- (449.5,215.73) -- (442.5,220.73) (377.5,87) -- (382.5,80) -- (387.5,87)  ;
%Curve Lines [id:da5441468874806336] 
\draw    (192.5,215) .. controls (293.5,206) and (378.5,152) .. (382.5,83) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da31033460930574375] 
\draw    (192.5,199) .. controls (293.5,190) and (363.5,134) .. (373.5,81) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da47724625643370233] 
\draw    (192.5,183) .. controls (280.5,169) and (328.5,142) .. (362.5,82) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da020885236261497853] 
\draw    (192.5,163) .. controls (262.5,162) and (304.5,143) .. (349.5,81) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da8078278035694941] 
\draw    (243.5,215) .. controls (340.5,194) and (373.5,166) .. (382.5,119) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da38951483876642956] 
\draw    (294.5,215) .. controls (340.5,202) and (356.5,195) .. (382.5,162) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da8319147976748231] 
\draw    (193.5,147) .. controls (268.5,147) and (305.5,115) .. (330.5,81) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da22478757053886234] 
\draw    (348.5,216) .. controls (359.5,211) and (378.5,217) .. (382.5,192) ;


%Curve Lines [id:da21433675413004827] 
\draw    (193.5,128) .. controls (264.5,122) and (276.5,110) .. (309.5,81) ;



% Text Node
\draw (373,224) node   {$L$};
% Text Node
\draw (186,224) node   {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (460,222) node   {$x_{3}$};
% Text Node
\draw (397,86) node   {$x_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (250,101) node   {$\theta ( x_{3})$};


\end{tikzpicture}




\caption{Scattering of a pulse by a single layer.}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Figure]

I would really appreciate any help on how I can make the figure look better.

Comment: which distance should be equidistant? why you not use some equations for your curves and `plot` macro?

Comment: I'm trying to plot the first curve repeatedly with equal distance between them on the y direction, so that the curves only occupy the region between 0 and L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0) rectangle (4,3);
  \foreach \X in {-2,-1.6,...,2}
   {\draw (0,\X) parabola ++(5,2);}
 \end{scope} 
 \draw[-stealth] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[below right]{$x_3$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,-0.5) node[above left]{$0$} -- (0,3)
 node[right=2em,yshift=-1em]{$\theta(x_3)$};
 \draw[-stealth] (4,-0.5) node[above left]{$L$} -- (4,3) node[below right]{$x_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! I'm sttruggling to add my theta and also x_2 on my y axis. Could you update your answer with this if it's not too much hassle?

Comment: @rodger_kicks You're welcome! I added them.

Comment: Thanks. This was so useful to see how to tex these types of images!